# JAXB and CDATA - How to create external bindings

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2

I have an XML of this type

```
 <Cols>
     <Col name="Amount" oldValue="123">456</Col>
     <Col name="Text" oldValue="ABC">DEF</Col>
     <Col name="CDATAText" oldValue="ABC<"><![CDATA[DEF<]]></Col>
 </Cols>
```

My Schema is something like this

```
 <xs:complexType name="NonCDATACol">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="oldValue" use="optional" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:complexType name="CDATACol">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="NonCDATACol"/>
    </xs:complexContent>
 </xs:complexType>
```

In the output when I Marshall CDATACol and and NonCDATACol I want them the element name to appear as Col. Also I am running to issues when customizing external bindings for CDATACol (CDATAAdapter). I get the error 'compiler was unable to honor this javaType customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings.'

Any help/sample would be appreciated. Thanks!!

I would like to achieve this using just RI, using other packages I will have to jump through a lot of hoops